# Facebook Sample App from SDK 3.0 for Android error "Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

When i run the Sample Android App from Facebook SDK 3.0 for Android i'm getting the error page "Misconfigured for Facebook Login. Press Okay to go back to the application without connecting to Facebook".

There is already a Facebook app in the device, if i uninstall that app the sample app getting me to login page of facebook. In logcat im getting the Error as **" Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider"**. I have given the hash key in dash board of facebook and also given the APP ID in the app. In dashboard i didnt find any option like enabling **Single Sign on**.

This might be a duplicate question. But i'm unable to find the solution to make the sample app run even a facebook app already exists in device. Help me to sort it out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

In the developer dashboard, under "Native Android App", you also need to set "Facebook Login" to "Enabled".  "Facebook Login" is the new name for "Single Sign on".

### If that does not work...

If you are logging in with a Session, try adding this code to your Session.StatusCallback call method:

```
if (exception != null) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you are using LoginButton to log in, implement LoginButton.OnErrorListener with the above code, and add the listener when the LoginButton gets created.

The resulting logcat should give you more information about what the problem is.

### Regarding the "Failed to find..." error:

Use a real device and make sure you have the latest version of the Facebook app installed.  The Facebook app included in the sdk is not recent enough to support attribution ids.

Comment: Thanks i already enabled the Facebook login but it didnt worked.

Comment: Hey thanks. While going by logcat error i found key mismatch and it specified a keyhash and i just copied the keyhash and added to my FB app settings. But when i create key using keytool it generates some other key which is not matching the key displayed in logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the step 4 correctly from the following link :-
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/3.0/

I think you have missed the keytool part from it where you have to add key hash to your developers account or you are not importing the FacebookSDK library in sample project.

Comment: I have created a app in facebook developers and given the Key Hash in it and got a APP_ID from facebook developers and declared it in the sample android activity and also imported the Facebook SDK without that we can't build the app.